# Restrict user to access other directory and file in NFS server

Tags: server, permissions, mount, nfs

I have one NFS server which will share to mutiple NFS client. The requirment is isolate each cilent ,make sure they could not access other's file. But the problem is NFS export could not restrict that.

In the NFS server, I created some directories and files for test like below:

NFS Server (192.168.172.1)

```
/home___ /nfs_share __ /directory1 _________exmaple1.txt
                   |             
                   |__ /directory2 _________example2.txt
```

/etc/export

`/home/nfs_share/directory1  ClientA(rw,no_root_squash,subtree_check)`

I expect that export will retricts CilentA can only access directory1, but I found that cilent can mount upper directory and still can access to directory2 and the files inside.

For example ClientA can directly mount /home/nfs_share, then he can access all the files under /nfs_share

`mount -t nfs 192.168.172.1:/home/nfs_share /root/nfs_client`

It is possible to retrict cilent to access other's files?

Comment: When using NFS without kerberos the security of all data in the NFS share depends on the integrity of all clients and the security of the network connections. If you use kerberos the security doesn't depend on all client machines because the server gives access to users with a valid kerberos ticket only.